# How do you UNION tables with schema differences?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I am currently working with a data set that relates to the current year.  Data that relates to each year is housed in a separate table.  When the data is queried, it is done so using a UNION ALL query.

Unfortunately, the data sets provided in the past do not share the same schema as that for the current year, some fields have been added, some retired, and others have been renamed.  I have no control over this.

In this case, how am I to do UNION ALL queries across these tables when the schema are different?  The differences are not very significant, but they deviate enough to cause problems.

Any suggestions?

Do I merge everything into one large table including all fields spanning across all years and then add new ones as they appear?  Or, do I continue to keep these tables separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one, don't try to UNION (actually UNION ALL would probably be more appropriate) with SELECT *.

You can:

- add columns to the sets that don't have a particular column, with token default / NULL values
- convert columns that are currently "the same" but use incompatible types
- simply leave out columns that aren't common enough to bother including

For example:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(d DATE, c INT, x FLOAT);

DECLARE @b TABLE(d DATETIME, c VARCHAR(32));

DECLARE @c TABLE(d DATE, x INT, y INT);

SELECT d, c = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), c), x = CONVERT(INT, x) FROM @a
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, d), c, x = NULL FROM @b
UNION ALL 
SELECT d, c = 'not supplied', x FROM @c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Aaron.  I am using a UNION ALL query, sorry for the confusion.  Currently, I am specifying the fields that remain consistent, but I would like a nice solution that I could SELECT * from, if possible.  Also, type-conversion isn't really something that I require.  If anything, the main issue is that the field names are not consistent across tables, but they store related data.  For example, in 2013 Street_Num might be Street_Number.  This is throwing a wrench in the gears.

Comment: No, there is no magic that will allow you to use SELECT *, unless you create a view for each table that exposes the data set you want to be in common across all tables, and then use SELECT * when you union against the views. But you have to do that mapping, manually, somewhere.

Comment: No Aaron!  My hopes and dreams. :(  So which way would be easier in your opinion?  Standardize the tables and populate NULL values?  If so, what about when fields are removed?  Or do I just go with a really messy UNION ALL query?  I'll dig further into views, but, is a view simply a pre-defined query on which another query is based?  That's what it sounds like, anyway.

Comment: I can't make that choice for you. If the older tables are no longer being actively used by other parts of the application, it might be easier to modify them to match the current schema, but if you're doing that just to allow SELECT * in your queries, I'd be absolutely against it. Write your queries to the schema, not the other way around.

Comment: Sounds like views are the way to go.  I too am not really a fan of altering the original table schema.  That said, in he event that I have conflicting or missing field names, can I use aliases and populate them with null values via a view?  I.E. this column didn't exist in 2003, but it exists now, so for 2003 make that column NULL and for 2013, return the data within that column.  Is this possible?  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I tried to illustrate in my example. Notice that column `x` doesn't exist in `@b`.

Comment: Ahhh, I do see.  You're brilliant.  Thanks for the help!  Does that same approach work if I needed to create an alias, i.e. Street_Num vs. Street_Number?

Comment: Yes. You should try it. :-)

Comment: @Addikt, you want to break that nasty select * habit anyway, it is a very poor practice.

Comment: @HLGEM is that so?  I thought that was the entire purpose behind using views.  In its current state, I'm looking at a UNION ALL query about a page long, and I would rather set up the query once in a view than have to reconstruct before every call.

Comment: @Addikt No, that is not the purpose of views. [Please read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).